# Order of returned records from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The records are ordered by id under controller, but when they are presented under `*.html.erb`, they are disorder again. I have to order them again. Why ??

```
In Controller

def show
...
@records.order(:id)
...
end
```

In show.html.erb, I have to do again, or it is disorder

```
<% for tmp_record in @records.order(:id) %>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your order should look like:

```
@records = Record.all.order('id desc')
```

You can also use a sort:

```
@records = Record.all.sort_by { |r| r.id }
```

Comment: `sort_by` is slow, loads everything first and then sorts in Ruby.